# How to create a custom, static library in SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, document-library

I want to create a static library of documents like the one below.

[image]

I'm working on a Mac, so if it is possible to not use SharePoint Designer, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show library content like picture above, you can add Content Query Tool WP, select source "/site", list type "Document Library", choose content type if neccessary or apply some filters, group style Default, Item style Image on left and so on and your library may look like list with bullets I think.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-list-HA010099248.aspx

Comment: So sorry, but I meant library and I wrote list.

Comment: The procedure is not mouch difficult

Answer (score 0):

On the Site home page click

All Site Content -> Create -> Document Library.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure for library creation with additional info is [here](http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1017)